# Has anything changed in iTunes to upload a new Binary.?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have an app in iTunes which i wanted to update with a new version. As according to the normal procedure, I have archived the file via XCode and then I tried to validate but it said "No suitable application records were found". After some search I came to know that the App status needs to be changed to ready to upload then I can do what I want. But when I logged in to iTunes, there is no option to upload a new binary, as can be seen in the image below..

[image]

instead there is some promo code option there. But in the previous window, there was an option to "ADD VERSION" as in the image,

[image]

but this link is not working as well.. When I click "Add Version" this page comes up.

[image]

and when I click continue on this page, it again sends me to the page showed in image 2.. Is there anything under maintenance in the site currently.? Can someone please check and respond.

Can anyone please tell me what shall be the proper procedure to follow in this case.

Thanx In advance..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple process, not iOS programming.

Comment: This might not be programming but even this is a developers concern man. Why be such code specific.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the process I followed is proper. When we click the member center link, it shows this "Under Maintenance" window..

[image]

So this is the problem. Untill they maintain their site, we cant accept member center terms, and hence we wont be able to upload any new version. So just wait for them to be up with the link again.

Answer (score 2):

Don't click Continue, click the "Member Center" link, and agree to the new program license agreement. This will allow you to create a new version.

Answer (score 1):

To Upload new binary, you need to have new version with app state 'Ready To upload Binary',

Click on Add Version and add update details...make app statue 'Ready to upload'. Then Upload.

[image]

Comment: Please see the updated question. I have already tried that earlier only.

Comment: for that you need to accept apple agreement in contract and tax section and member centre - 2place.

Answer (score 0):

Some maintenance might be going on. U can wait for a day and try later.